# Three20 doesn't compile with Xcode 4.5.2 and Xcode 4.6.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5, three20

I have a sample project with the help of Three20 framework used. while run on xcode 4.4.1 it works fine.in that same project while run on Xcode 4.5.2 and Xcode 4.6.2 i am getting below error.

```
some of the errors are :

/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:109:5: Unknown type name '_tapCount'; did you mean 'ItemCount'?
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:109:15: Expected identifier or '('
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:110:5: Use of undeclared identifier '_locationInWindow'
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:111:5: Use of undeclared identifier '_previousLocationInWindow'
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:113:43: Use of undeclared identifier '_locationInWindow'
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:114:5: Use of undeclared identifier '_view'; did you mean 'view'?
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:115:5: Use of undeclared identifier '_window'
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:116:5: Use of undeclared identifier '_phase'
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:117:5: Use of undeclared identifier '_touchFlags'
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:118:5: Use of undeclared identifier '_touchFlags'
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:119:5: Use of undeclared identifier '_timestamp'
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:127:3: Use of undeclared identifier '_phase'; did you mean 'phase'?
/three20/src/Three20UI/Sources/UIViewAdditions.m:128:3: Use of undeclared identifier '_timestamp'
```

[image]

Comment: Just as a question:  Open up Xcode 4.4.1 and examine the UITouch.h header file.  Do you see these variables declared there?  They are not declared in the iOS 6.1 headers, so I assume they are not available for use anymore (if they are there in the UITouch.h file in iOS 5.x then this confirms my theory but I don't have access to them).  This framework was abandoned 2 years ago so I don't know why you want to try to use it.  This class also relied heavily on implementation details, which is fine if is being actively maintained but otherwise is just a recipe for breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running an up-to-date version, you probably have `DEBUG_TOUCH` defined. Undefine it and the errors should disappear.